# Spring Mongo - An aggregation to order by objects in an array

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following data:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectID("5e2fa881c3a1a70006c5743c"),
    "name": "Some name",
    "policies": [
        {
            "cId": "dasefa-2738-4cf0-90e0d568",
            "weight": 12
        },
        {
            "cId": "c640ad67dasd0-92f981583568",
            "weight": 50
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm able to query this with Spring Mongo fine, however I want to be able to order the policies by `weight`

At the moment I get my results fine with:

`return mongoTemplate.find(query, CArea::class.java)`

However say I make the following aggregations:

```
val unwind = Aggregation.unwind("policies")
val sort = Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC,"policies.weight")
```

How can I go and actually apply those to the returned results above? I was hoping that the `dot annotation would do the job in my query however didnt do anything` e.g. `Query().with(Sort.by(options.sortDirection, "policies.weight"))`

Any help appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be able to convert the aggregtion in my answer to spring mongo code?

Comment: Hi, I actually ended up doing the sort client side, as thee wasn't much data.
I still need to look in how to write the aggregation you shared in Spring. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familier with Spring Mongo, but I guess you can convert the following aggregation to spring code.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$policies"
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "policies.weight": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id",
      "policies": {
        "$push": "$policies"
      },
      parentFields: {
        $first: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $mergeObjects: [
          "$parentFields",
          {
            policies: "$policies"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

This will result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5e2fa881c3a1a70006c5743c",
    "name": "Some name",
    "policies": [
      {
        "cId": "c640ad67dasd0-92f981583568",
        "weight": 50
      },
      {
        "cId": "dasefa-2738-4cf0-90e0d568",
        "weight": 12
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/do-F28eNAwZ)